# Azure B2C Custom Policy - change sign in from email to phone

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

Currently I am capturing the users email and phone when they sign up. Once they are signed up, they log in with their email and password. I would like to change this so they login with their phone and password instead of their email address. What update do I need to make in my custom policies to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

There is [GitHub sample](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/signup-signin-with-phone-number) Where you can login users solely on Phone Number and MFA via SMS or Phone Call. This approach is passwordless. Hope this will helps your query

Comment: Does it have to be passwordless when logging in with phone?

Comment: Its providing [One-time passwords](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/phone-authentication) which help minimize the risk of your users forgetting or having their passwords compromised.

Comment: Does this still allow social login so the phone number sign in is only used for local account?

Comment: The phone sign in is only used for the local accounts. With the Social Idp integration in the custom policy will allow you to sign in with social login as well.

Comment: Do we have the option of having a password with the phone number for local accounts?

Comment: You need to implement this with two custom policies:

1.A sign-up or sign-in policy that allows sign-up for a local account using a phone umber and sign-in for a local account using an e-mail address or a phone number.
2.A linking policy that allows linking of an e-mail address to a local account that has been registered using a phone number.

Comment: I have the custom policies setup now where we are just validating a phone number and setting the password without asking for email. The users phone number is being set as the username. I then changed the sign in to use Username instead of Email. The login works but the forgot password link is failing. is it possible to handle forgot password without an email?

Comment: Try an Alternatively redirect properly to normal SSPR experience when the "forgot password" link is clicked

Comment: Can you elaborate on trying an alternative redirect? do you have an example of this?

Comment: When user clicking on "I forgot my password" redirect the user automatically to a generic Microsoft-branded password reset page

Comment: what is the url for the Microsoft branded reset page? and can you confirm this will work with just the phone number and not an email address?

Comment: Url for Microsoft password reset page `https://aka.ms/sspr` and please go through the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/authentication/tutorial-enable-sspr#select-authentication-methods-and-registration-options) helps you in clear understanding on SSPR